# Save Image from RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a coloring app and I want to save my image (which is in a
RelativeLayout) on the sd card. Below is my code.

I am inflating another layout, which consists of my image. I am drawing in the RelativeLayout, but I can't save the image that is in the RelativeLayout.

**DrawingActivity:**

```
public class DrawingActivity extends Activity {
    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint   mPaint;
     MyDrawView myDrawView;
      RelativeLayout parent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawing);


       parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.singleparent);
        myDrawView = new MyDrawView(this);
        parent.addView(myDrawView);
        Activity context;
        //RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.trans, null);
      parent.addView(child);




    }

   public void color(View v)
   {
       switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button3:
           parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
             parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;

        case R.id.button5:
             parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            break;
        }
    }
 public void save(View v)
 {



 }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_drawing, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public class MyDrawView extends View {



        public MyDrawView(Context c) {
            super(c);

            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

            mPaint = new Paint();
            mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            mPaint.setDither(true);
            mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
        }
        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void clear(){
            mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            invalidate();
            System.gc();
        }



    }

}
```

**activity_drawing.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Draw" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Erase" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/singleparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:background="#00FF00" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="color"
        android:text="Blue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Save" 
        android:onClick="save"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button6"
        android:onClick="color"
        android:text="Red" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:onClick="color"
        android:text="Green" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**trans.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

     >

    <ImageView 

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/rrr"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```